# acces to parent tests from child tests in maven

Tags: java, maven, web, jar, war

I have project which contains of 2 jars

core.jar - parent

ui.war - child

in ui.pom.xml I write that this module depends on core.jar

In ui tests I want use source code core tests. How I must configure it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a test-jar like the following:

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

which gives you the opportunity to use the test classes in an other project. Just define the dependency in the other project like this:

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>groupId</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
      <type>test-jar</type>
      <version>version</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  ...
</project>
```

But it is not possible to use the sources code core tests.

Answer (score 0):

you need to configure the core to create a jar containing the test-code, which you then reference in ui with the classifier "test-jar" and the scope "test", see: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-attached-tests.html